# Definition of finite field with fixed characteristic

Tags: definition, finite-fields, cryptography, discrete-logarithms

In this article [Discrete logarithms in quasi-polynomial time in finite fields of fixed characteristic](https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/751.pdf) the term *finite fields of fixed characteristic* is not defined and I couldn't find it on the literature, too.

- What is the definition of **finite fields of fixed characteristic**

Comment: Where did you search? This definition is in every introduction to basic algebra. A field is an algebraic structure where you can add, multiply and invert (if you didn't know, then fields can be googled without any problems). Characteristic $p$ means that $1 + \dots + 1 = 0$ where we add $p$ copies of the unit $1$.

Comment: I'm not looking for characteristics. Why the term **fixed** used in the front of it? What additional property it brings to characteristics.

Comment: It just means that we fix a characteristic $p$.

Comment: I don't think so, In the DLog problem the characteristic is given by the problems that one is attacking. It should say more in this context.

Comment: Isn't that even exactly what they say in the first paragraph? They fix a characteristic $p$ and consider solving the DLog problem for fields $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$. The idea is that having fixed a characteristic, we reduce to a more specific (but still nice) setting where we may be able to say more than in the general setting. (In particular, they form an important subcategory of the category of fields.)

Comment: Well, I've never seen a problem in the DLOG that the characteristic is not fixed in this sense. so the word a bit meaningless and there are a couple of articles that use this word and don't define it exactly.

Comment: They just want to say that the paper does not consider all finite fields at once but rather for a fixed characteristic...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The term *quasi-polynomial time* means quasi-polynomial in...which parameters? What *fixed characteristic* says is that the problem is quasi-polynomial in the field size as the field size varies, as long as we keep the characteristic fixed.

So, for instance, if their algorithm takes $\le C2^pk^r$ steps over a field of characteristic $p$ and size $k$ for some constants $C,r$, then it is polynomial for fields of fixed characteristic, but exponential in the characteristic.

Comment: The last paragraph hits the point. Thanks.